# What's the difference between declaring an array in C like this: int a[n] and int a<n>

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, declaration, rpc

I was trying to do some RPC matrix sending from client to server... and some gut who I don't remember put his .x file with some "array" ¿? declared like this: int X <100>; within an strcuture of the .x... this is his structure created:

```
struct X_array{
    int X <100>;
    int X_size;
}
```

Funny thing is that in his client code he's got some like this: (i'll give it kinda sumarized)

```
printf("Give size)";
scanf("%d",&n);
average_1_arg.X.X_len=n;
avegare_1_arg.X_size=n;
average_1_arg.X.X_val=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

In his .x, that function is declared as:
float average(X_array)=1;

WHERE DOES HE GET THOSE PARTS OF HIS STRCUTURE?

And the most insane thing for me is that I compiled his .x from 0 with "rpcgen -a -C dum.x", then I wrote the client and server the very same as he has in his .c's, I mean, client and server .c's and after that put on console "make -f Makefile.dum" and then ran the ./dum_server and ./dum_client and everything works good with no errors. My mindblowing is that with the parts from the X_array structure that are not in the .x, are in the client code and those work without even declaring the type of that variable; even if those were pointers from the "int X <100>;" stuff, there is an int (.X_len) and an acutal pointer (.X_val) in there.
Now I have experimented by changing those pair of "<>" for pair of "[]", and compiled until the command "make -f Makefile.dum", where the compiled gave me many errors. I'd appreciate your help.

A buddy from college gave that code to me, so I don't knwo its origin to ask directly to the creator. Thanks. (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int X <100>;` isn't C.  It's XDR input for [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), so refer to its documentation for the syntax.  RPCGEN will process its input file into C code, which may include automatically declaring a struct with a bunch of additional members.

See 6.8 (3) in [the RPCGEN manual](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/22.rpcgen/paper.pdf) for "variable-length array declarations", which in particular explains the creation of the `_len` and `_val` members.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I'll check it out. I thought RPC with C was only about basic C syntaxis by what I remember being taught.

Comment: I was so able to do what I wanted to!
I read that documentation you sent. You saved my life, dude!
I hope that soon I'll get to post that code on my github account and I'll link that in some next comment. All of the code commented as much as possible. 
Have a nice day, afternoon, or night... according to when you are watching at this. <3